# how to avoid overlapping label and textbox in html form

Tags: css

```
cssfile:
#Title
{
position:relative;
left:130px;
top:210px;
}
#title
{
position:relative;
left:190px;
top:210px;
}
#Subtitle
{
position:relative;
left:130px;
top:410px;
}
#subtitle
{
position:relative;
left:210px;
top:410px;
}     
enter code here
<html>
<label id=Title>Title</label>
<label id=Subtitle>Subtitle</label>
<input id='title' name="title" type='text' value="<?php echo $title;?>"/>
<input id='subtitle' name="subtitle" type='text' value="<?php echo $subtitle;?>"/>
</html>
```

> The textbox and label gets overlapped with each other while displaying the values of html textboxes. I use the position:relative for the label and textbox. How to overcome from this problem..

Comment: Please provide HTML and CSS. Without it we cannot help you.

Comment: please refer the edits

Comment: what is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

wrong

```
<label id=Title>Title</label>
<label id=Subtitle>Subtitle</label>
```

id fail, lack use `""` or `''` and no define `for=""`

```
<label for="title">Title:</label> 
<input type="text" id="title" name="titleother" value="<?php echo $title;?>"/>
<br/>
<label for="Subtitle">Subtitle</label>
<input id='subtitle' name="subtitleother" type='text' value="<?php echo $subtitle;?>"/>
```